# ReactDOM render to multiple nodes

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have to render React component on multiple places across the page. So I have two `divs` with same `ids` and I want to render same React component on both places:

```
<h1>Title 1</h1>
<div id='react-component'>/<div>
.
.
.

<h1>Title 2</h1>
<div id='react-component'>/<div>
```

In React it renders component nly on one place:

```
const node = document.querySelector('#react-component');
if (!node) {
  return null;
}
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, node);
```

What would be the most efficient way to solve this? Is it possible for `ReactDOM` to render same component on multiple nodes?

Answer (score 0):

[Probably shouldn't use two same IDs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme) But you can do the same with classes !

Then you simply have to get them using

`document.querySelectorAll('.yourclass')` *(Since querySelector only gives you the first instance of the found item)*